# Appended HTML not recognized by jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, contextmenu

User adds a new note. Note is added to database and returns HTML of the note to display to user and returns context menu for that note:

```
success: function( result ) {

   var resultArray = eval( result );

   $( "#notes").append( resultArray[0] );
   $( "#notes").append( resultArray[1] );
}
```

resultArray[0] is:

```
<tr class="getMenuNote contextMenuPointer-note" id="<?php echo $note->id ?>">
   /*details of note here... nothing interesting and works just fine*/
</tr>
```

resultArray[1] is:

```
<div class="contextMenu" id="menu-<?php echo $note->id ?>" class="dropdown clearfix">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="" class="deleteNote" noteID="<?php echo $note->id ?>">Delete</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The issue is that when user clicks on the note it is supposed to call .getMenuNote. which was loaded on document load. I understand that .getMenuNote doesnt know the newly appended HTML exists and cannot link it together, but how do I get it to know it exists?

I looked into .on() and .live() but none seem to work for me. Looking for a solution with code, rather than theory.

Thanks all!

***EDITED***
Here is the event handler:

```
$( ".getMenuNote" ).click( "contextmenu", function ( e ) {

   noteID = $( this ).attr( "id" );

   $( "#menu-" + noteID ).css( {
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.page
   } );

   return false;
} );
```

Comment: `on()` with event delegation would be the solution. What have you tried?

Comment: Uhm, where's the event handler that calls getMenuNote ?

Comment: @adeneo added .getMenuNote

Comment: @JasonP Reading about on() it seems like solution, but I dont have an idea how to implement it. Ive not gone very far in that direction yet.

Comment: It's a little confusing, are you trying to trigger the contextMenu, or just clicking an element with the very confusing class contextMenu ?

Comment: @adeneo Trying to trigger the contextMenu

Comment: Then try `$('#notes').on('contextmenu', '.getMenuNote', function() {...`

Comment: What is `$( "#notes")`, a `<table>`? you are `.append`-ing a `<tr>` and then a `<div>` which creates invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$( "#notes").on("click", ".getMenuNote", function(e){
   var noteID = this.id;

   $( "#menu-" + noteID ).css( {
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.page
   } );
});
```

Also, if `#notes` is a `<table>` then you may want to append your HTML like so:

```
$( "#notes").append(resultArray[0])
            .find("tr:last-child")
            .append(resultArray[1]);
```

One last thing...
I'm not a PHP guy (I use .NET), but I wouldn't think that php code (`<?php echo $note->id ?>`) would render if you are injecting it into the DOM via jQuery after an AJAX call. You should return the HTML markup with the id already included.